# Incorrect forms authentication timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, forms-authentication

I want to make "remember time" on a site something aroun one week. In default mvc 3 application I set this changes:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="10880" slidingExpiration="true" />
```

But, it is not enought. After half an hour site forget me. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did you set propert timeout for the forms authentication ticket and also the `isPersistent` parameter should be set as `true`.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket
(
   1,                 // version
   username,          // user name
   DateTime.Now,      // issue date
   expiration,        // this should also be set to 10880
   rememberMeChecked, // this should be true
   null,              // additional data
   "/"                // cookie path
);
```

For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851155/remember-me-functionality-in-asp-net-form-authentication-doesnt-work).